# Changed behaviour of read.csv since R 3.1.0

Tags: r, csv

Since upgrading from R 3.0.3 to 3.1.0 I have had troubles with `read.csv` as something seems to have changed in the underlying behaviour of `read.table`.

More precisely, I have a lot of CSV files that were once written using numpy. In general, these CSV files contain nothing more than a few columns of real values, e.g.:

```
foo,bar,baz
 1.162372390042962556e+00, 2.578863142444774326e+00, 9.740731078696458098e+02
-1.162361054912456337e+00, 6.006949912541799108e-01, 9.740731078696458098e+02
 1.327779088525234963e+00, 2.448484270423362030e+00, 9.664414899055957449e+02
```

Up to R 3.0.3, everything worked just fine when reading these files. Now I get this:

```
> tmp <- read.csv("foo.csv")
> str(tmp)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ foo: Factor w/ 3 levels " 1.162372390042962556e+00",..: 1 3 2
 $ bar: Factor w/ 3 levels " 2.448484270423362030e+00",..: 2 3 1
 $ baz: Factor w/ 2 levels " 9.664414899055957449e+02",..: 2 2 1
```

Will I have to change *all* of my codebase? Or is this merely a bug in 3.1.0?

Comment: This was recently fixed.  You will need a sufficiently recent version of R.  See http://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-devel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [NEWS](http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/NEWS.html) file explains a change to the default behaviour for unrepresentable decimal numbers:

> `type.convert()` (and hence by default `read.table()`) returns a character
>   vector or factor when representing a numeric input as a double would
>   lose accuracy. Similarly for complex inputs.
>
> If a file contains numeric data with unrepresentable numbers of
>   decimal places that are intended to be read as numeric, specify
>   colClasses in `read.table()` to be "numeric".

Your numbers have 18 decimal places, doubles can only accurately represent about 15.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug and yes, you have to change your code.

From the CRAN website:

> type.convert() (and hence by default read.table()) returns a character
>   vector or factor when representing a numeric input as a double would
>   lose accuracy. Similarly for complex inputs.
>
> If a file contains numeric data with unrepresentable numbers of
>   decimal places that are intended to be read as numeric, specify
>   colClasses in read.table() to be "numeric".